# How to continue execution after raising assertion error in selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, pytest

I have written the code as below.
If the element is displayed then it has to log the error message at the end of the complete execution
If the element not displayed then report the message as

> "Not displayed"

```
try:
  if self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"").is_displayed():
            raise AssertionError("Element should not be displayed")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        self.log.info("Element not displayed")
```

If element displayed then raising the assertion error where execution will stop if the element does not exist then continuing the execution.

How can I write the script for both the conditions?

Answer (score 1):

use else

```
try:
  print("Hello")
except:
  print("Something went wrong")
else:
  print("Nothing went wrong")
finally:
 print("This will be printed irrespective of the outcome")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this is just a case of using the proper syntax. You don't need a try / except here. Using what you put in the question:

```
if self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"").is_displayed():
   raise AssertionError("Element should not be displayed")
else:
   self.log.info("Element not displayed")
```